# Cannot save the parameter after changing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have the next regular expression:

```
regex = /(?:.be\/|\/watch\?v=|\/(?=p\/))([\w\/\-]+)/
```

For example I have the next YouTube URL: `https://youtu.be/7FcfSxrRU`. After this regexp I do:

```
givenUrl = params[:url].match(regex)[0] 
newUrl = givenUrl.split('.be/')[1]
```

this code gives me the result. The `newUrl` is that I need, but when I try to save it like

```
params[:url] = newUrl
```

I get an error,

```
undefined method []' for nil:NilClass`
```

for the givenUrl.

I did try to save it here:

```
permitted = params.permit(:url, :title, :description, :post_type, :category_id)
```

What is the problem? Why I get this error?

**UPDATE**
*It's my def where I permit parameters and add to database table*

```
def check_params
  regex = /(?:.be\/|\/watch\?v=|\/(?=p\/))([\w\/\-]+)/

  givenUrl = params[:url].match(regex)[0]
  newUrl = givenUrl.split('.be/')[1]

  params[:url] = newUrl
  permitted = params.permit(:url, :title, :description, :post_type, :category_id)
end
```

The error is in the next line:

```
givenUrl = params[:url].match(regex)[0]
```

Comment: Is this all in a controller?  Can you show the code in context in the controller?

Comment: what line is the error message referring to?

Comment: post the controller code as well as the params or the form so that we can get a better understanding of the context. If this is in the model `params` is no longer available to you and should be referenced by the model method instead but without a bit more insight this question will quickly become stagnant if not closed all together

Comment: @nzifnab I did add to my question the controller def

Comment: @margo this `givenUrl = params[:url].match(regex)[0]`

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade Which line is the error on? That information belongs in the question itself, not the comments. Looks like there's nothing in the matches.

Comment: @DaveNewton this `givenUrl = params[:url].match(regex)[0]`

Comment: What is `params[:url]`? It looks like your regex isn't matching that URL, so `match(regex)` is returning nil, and then it's trying to do `nil[0]` which it can't...

Comment: @nzifnab no, it's not null. Please, read my question again

Comment: either params is nil or the match is nil. Put some logging in your methods to print out some of these variables to prove that you're getting back what you expect to

Comment: You're confusing me :/  Why did you say "The error is in the next line:  `givenUrl = params[:url].match(regex)[0]`" if that's not the case? If that's where the error is, then it's the `.match(regex)[0]` that is causing it (probably).  Your best bet is going to be logging some of your variables so you can see what they are.  What does `params.inspect` look like at the beginning of this action?  `Rails.logger.debug(params.inspect)` and then you can `tail -f log/development.txt`